# Combing 2 lists, n elements each at a time

Tags: python, list, element

Given two equal length lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Is there anyway to combine them, the first 3 (or more generally and for larger lists, the first n) elements of each at a time, such that I get an list output below:

`c = [1,2,3,a,b,c,4,5,6,d,e,f,7,8,9,f,h,i]`

I've seen solutions which show how to do it for 1 element at a time from each list but I can't translate that to n elements.

Comment: are lists always the same length ?

Comment: yes, forgot to mention that

Comment: What is your desired output if there are 10 elements (i.e. append `10` to `a` and append `'j'` to `b`). Should they be appended to `c`?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        a[p:p+n] + b[p:p+n] for p in range(0, len(a), n)))
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with simple `for`-loop and `slices`, where `n` - arrays length:

```
result = []

for j in range(0, len(a), n):
    result += a[j:j+n] + b[j:j+n]

print(result)
```

Comment: I'm getting this: `[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 2, 3, 4, 'b', 'c', 'd', 3, 4, 5, 'c', 'd', 'e']` which doesn't seem to be what OP wants.

Comment: Yup, this method doesn't work. You don't have a `step` parameter in your range.

Comment: If you're going to only use `j`, just do `for j in range(0, len(a), n)` In any case, @nosklo has a safer / more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional efficient (fast) way without any mutation using the itertools `grouper` recipe. Another advantage is that it can be used with any number of lists, not just two.

```
from itertools import zip_longest, chain

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i'.split(',')

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue = None):
    """Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    """
    args = [iter(iterable)]*n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def multi_round_robin(*iterables, n, fillvalue = None):
    """ Collect data from multiple iterables in groups
    # multi_round_robin('ABCD', 'EFGH', n=2) --> A B E F C D G H
    """
    for tups in zip(*(grouper(itr, n, fillvalue) for itr in iterables)):
        return chain.from_iterable(tups)

list(multi_round_robin(a, b, n=3))
# --> [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list slicing

**Ex:**

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
res = []
for i in range(0, len(a), 3):
    res.extend(a[i:i+3] + b[i:i+3])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try list comprehension:

```
lst = [a[i:i+3] + b[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]
result = [i for s in lst for i in s]
print (result)
```

**Answer**

```
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function such as the following

```
def create_list(arr1, arr2, n):
    c = []
    for i in range(len(arr1)//n):
        for j in range(3):
            c.append(arr1[(i*3)+j])
        for j in range(3):
            c.append(arr2[(i*3)+j])
    return c
```

This should give you the kind of list you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a small function to perform this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
b = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']

def interleave( listA, listB, interval):
    result = []
    while len(listB) >= interval and len(listA) >= interval:
        [result.append( listA.pop(0) ) for i in range(interval)]
        [result.append( listB.pop(0) ) for i in range(interval)]
    #Add remainder of lists in order
    [result.append( item ) for item in listA]
    [result.append( item ) for item in listB]
    return result

print( interleave(a, b, 3) )
```

results in

```
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
In [14]: a
Out[14]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [15]: b
Out[15]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

In [17]: al = [a[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a), 3)]

In [18]: bl = [b[i:i+3] for i  in range(0, len(b), 3)]

In [19]: al
Out[19]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

In [20]: bl
Out[20]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

In [23]: [k for i in list(zip(al, bl)) for j in i for k in j]
Out[23]: [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 4, 5, 6, 'd', 'e', 'f', 7, 8, 9, 'g', 'h', 'i']
```